# Problems updating HP laptop graphics driver

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, ati-mobility-radeon, switchable-graphics

So since I installed 64 bit Windows 7 on my HP laptop I have problem finding updated drivers for my graphics card.  The only driver that works is the old driver I found on HP website

My laptop has Radeon 7470M and Intel 3000.

Every time I want to install a newer beta driver my laptop boots in 1024x768 resolution so it simply doesn't work.

I did uninstall the old driver before I installed the new one but it still doesn't work.

I saw something about this saying that you have replace old installer with new one or something like that. Can you tell me how?

Comment: What is wrong with the driver that does work that it has to be replaced?

Answer (score 2):

In general, updating graphics card drivers can be really tricky and annoying. 
You definitely SHOULD NOT update if everything is working. In 99% of cases, downloading new drivers doesn't help performance or basically anything else (in fact, it can harm performance).

The only issues you seem to be having are when you go to update, so don't try to update.

If you found any working drivers, use it and don't worry.

Comment: This is a sad but true fact.  Generally the only time updated drivers will help is with new hardware/driver combos while they work out performance quirks and bugs.  After a while performance stabilizes and you only see benefits shown for newer hardware.